# How to add a keyboard layout to the login screen?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, login-screen, keyboard-layout

The login screen only shows my default keyboard layout, how can I add different ones, so that other users can select these if they want?

Additionaly: is there a way to allow users to select arbitrary keyboard layouts upon login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the layouts that you desire under System Settings --> Keyboard layout, and when you login you will be able to choose the layout of your choice.

[image]

For 14.04

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't know that this is a per-user setting. How can I add one permanently for the guest user though?

Comment: AFAIK. I don't think that you can do for guest, since its a limited account.

Comment: This doesn't work on Trusty.

Comment: @poolie It works on Trusty (14.04), see added image in my answer.

Comment: OK, this doesn't work _for me_ on Trusty. I never get that layout chooser.

Comment: @poolie, perhaps you use different flavor of Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm no longer using Ubuntu. However at the time this was the regular flavor.