# Keyboard layout selection menu on login screen Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard-layout

How do I allow keyboard layout selection menu in the login screen (Ubuntu 22.04)? Toggling this option on has been possible [through settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171603/how-to-add-a-keyboard-layout-to-the-login-screen), but I do not see this option in newer versions. How do I a allow it?

Comment: Assuming you are on standard Ubuntu, "newer versions" use GDM as the login manager instead of LightDM. Can you please elaborate and let us know what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson what does that mean? I have a computer with different users and two keyboards with different layouts. I want users to be able to choose the keyboard layout that works for them.

Comment: Ok. But is your concern the login screen itself (username/password) or the effective keyboard once logged in? As regards the latter, the keyboard layout set by the user at first login will stay as their layout once logged in.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson no, the concern is during the login screen. If possible I would like a scroll down menu in the login screen to type the password in the preferred layout (similar to the top menu available after loggin in). See the linked question for picture examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by including the two layouts in question in the `/etc/default/keyboard` file. Example:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us,fr"
XKBVARIANT=","
```

That should result in a layout selector on the login screen, letting the users pick either the English (US) or the French layout.

Comment: Thanks! Note: `XKBVARIANT=","` has to be that way adding qwerty or any other options makes this answer not work.

Comment: @Mauricio: Not sure what you mean by "not work". If you want variants, you need to make `XKBVARIANT` reflect that. My example does not include variants. But I can elaborate the answer if you like.

Comment: I tried to add variants, but your answer did the work much better.

Comment: Yes, for example I had `XKBVARIANT="latin9"` and the keyboard selector did not appear.

Comment: @krumpelstiltskin: Well, you need to do it right. There is no `latin9` variant for the `us` layout. But this should work: `XKBVARIANT=",latin9"`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: ahhh... got it!